# This expression is not callable. Type '{ Shop: typeof Shop; }' has no call signatures. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I don't know how and why I'm getting this error in React.

I'm trying to build this components:

```
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>ShopsList</div>
                {this.state.loading || !this.state.shops ? 
                    (
                        <div></div>
                    ) : 
                    (
                        <div>
                            {this.state.shops.map(shop=>Shop(shop))} # Line with the error
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
```

but the program won't compile and gives the following message:

> This expression is not callable.   Type '{ Shop: typeof Shop; }' has
> no call signatures

`Shop` is imported in the following way
`import Shop from '../Shop';`

with the folder `../Shop` having the following structure:

```
Shop/
       Shop.tsx
       index.tsx
```

and `index.tsx` has this content:

```
import Shop from "./Shop";
export default {Shop}
```

Shop has been defined in this way, which *has* a constructor:

```
import React from 'react';

export interface IShopProps {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    phone_number?: string;
}

class Shop extends React.Component<IShopProps, {}> {
    
    constructor(props: IShopProps) {
        super(props);
    }
    
    render() {     
        return (
            <div className='shopRow'>
                <div className='shopName'>{this.props.name}</div>
                <div className='shopNumber'>{this.props.phone_number ? this.props.phone_number : "numero non disponibile"}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
};

export default Shop;
```

What am I doing wrong? I already tried looking up on SO for that message and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61416852/this-expression-is-not-callable-type-string-has-no-call-signatures) post, but to me it doesn't seem I have done the same error.

Edit:
I also tried as suggested by @Viet:

```
{this.state.shops.map((shop, index) => <Shop key={index} {...shop} />)}
```

and still get the error:

> JSX element type 'Shop' does not have any construct or call
> signatures.  TS2604

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Shop` is the component so you should use it with `<>`:

```
{this.state.shops.map((shop, index) => <Shop key={index} {...shop} />)}
```

The problem is you import `Shop` wrong way. Just update `import` in your component where you use `Shop` component like this:

```
import { Shop } from "../Shop" // from index file
```

Or like this

```
import Shop from "../Shop/Shop" // from Shop file
```

Comment: I still get the same error, I had already tried that

Comment: How do you import `Shop`?

Comment: I edited the question with the explanation of how I import Shop

Comment: I see. But i don't see how do you import from component where you use `{this.state.shops.map(shop=>Shop(shop))}`

Comment: I imported it with `import Shop from '../Shop``.

Here is the whole file: https://pastebin.com/JWJpBYxd